# extract checkbox value in RGTK2

Tags: r, gtk2

I use the code below to create a checkbox for user to check/uncheck it.

```
input.form1.015.checkbox <- gtkCheckButton("15_check")
```

I wonder how I can extract the value of the checkbox (i.e. whether it is checked or not)

Currently I use the following:

```
gSignalConnect(input.form1.015.checkbox,"clicked",function(widget)print("Hello world1!"))
```

But I think this is not very nice, as I need to have the initial value of the checkbox first.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `active` property holds this value. You can access it directly via `$` and `$<-`, as in `input.form1.015.checkbox$active <- TRUE`, or the methods `getActive` and `setActive`.